Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
The error for the code is as follows:

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
.onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'tidyverse', details:
call: NULL
error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyr’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
namespace ‘cli’ 3.3.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.6.1 is required

I have tried to update R and the packages, but none of that seems to work.
The code I am running:
install.packages("rtools")
remove.packages("vctrs")
install.packages("vctrs")
remove.packages("rlang")
install.packages("rlang")
library(tidyverse)

SB_Churn %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = 6:19, names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Value)) +
  geom_histogram(fill = "purple") +
  facet_wrap(~Variable, scales = 'free') +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank())


Start a fresh R session, run install.packages("cli"). If that succeeds, use install.packages("tidyverse").

Not a cause of your issue, but you don't need library(dplyr) if you use library(tidyverse) (I deleted library(dplyr) as part of an edit FYI).
